# install pillow - error: ld returned 1 - windows

Tags: python, gcc, mingw, pip, python-imaging-library

```
(Many more undefs...)
build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0x55a6): undefined
 reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_FromString'

build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0x55bb): undefined
 reference to `_imp__PyDict_SetItemString'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build\temp
.win-amd64-3.4\Release\_imaging.o: bad reloc address 0x14 in section `.data'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

To me it seems like some linking error, but I have no idea how to correct it, I've tried few things already, but unfortunately no working solutions yet. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Command line output from "pip install pillow" using MinGW.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience, that way lies only madness.

I'd recommend downloading a [prebuilt windows binary](http://lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs#pillow)

---

My guess for this particular error is that your compiler does not match the one python 3.4 was built with - if you're upgrading from a working 2.7 setup, that would make sense, since python switched from MSVC 2008 to MSVC 2010.

I was able to get it to compile with the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 compiler, but with neither JPEG or PNG support.

Comment: It was downloaded and installed as 3.4

Comment: Well for now a prebuilt binary will be sufficient as it allows me to get the work done. But I still would like an actual solution to the problem

Comment: _"It was downloaded and installed as 3.4"_ - what was?

Comment: I meant python release 3.4, it was downloaded and installed today (pc after format)

Comment: @Kwydin: Did you download a 3.4 binary or build the 3.4 source? The pip modules need to be built with a compatible compiler to core!

Comment: I've used their Win installer, so it seems to just unpack the binary, I'll redo it tomorrow since its really late right now.